# How to get multiple responses per second with Get Request using ESP32

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I'm using an ESP32 controller to send Get requests to a page. I can get 1 response per second using the `http` protocol and one response every three seconds using `HTTPS`. I would like to get as many as 3 responses per second if possible. Is there a faster way to get these responses and is the problem with my ESP32, the code, or the server itself? I'm not sure if it helps but my ESP32 is sending the Get request to an ASP.NET application running on a Windows server through an Amazon Web Services EC2 instance. My API is simply returning true or false.

Here is the code running on the ESP32:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiMulti.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#define USE_SERIAL Serial

WiFiMulti wifiMulti;

//Certificate when using HTTPS
/*
const char* ca = \ 
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"examplecertificate\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
*/

void setup() {

    USE_SERIAL.begin(115200);
    for(uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
        USE_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] WAIT %d...\n", t);
        USE_SERIAL.flush();
        delay(1000);
    }
    wifiMulti.addAP("ssid", "password");
}

void loop() {
    // wait for WiFi connection
    if((wifiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {

        HTTPClient http;
        //USE_SERIAL.print("[HTTP] begin...\n");
        //http.begin("https://example.com/webapi/controller/getstatus/0", ca); //Using HTTPS takes 3 seconds
        http.begin("http://example.com/webapi/controller/getstatus/0"); //Using HTTP takes 1 second

        //USE_SERIAL.print("[HTTP] GET...\n");
        // start connection and send HTTP header
        int httpCode = http.GET();

        // httpCode will be negative on error
        if(httpCode > 0) {

            // file found at server
            if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
                String payload = http.getString();
                USE_SERIAL.println(payload);
            }
        } else {
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
        }
        http.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you checked what the response speed of your server is? Reusing the http client will probably allow you to reuse the connection (assuming the server supports HTTP 1.1 with persistent connections). A websocket is likely to be faster if you want to continuously query a server for a small value

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have no idea how to check that but I will research this.

Comment: A full TLS handshake will take around 2 seconds on the ESP32. You must keep the connection open, as Alan suggested, to avoid massive delays when using HTTPS. With plain HTTP 1 req/s is quite sluggish - I suspect calling `wifiMulti.run()` is not needed on every loop cycle.

Comment: Or use a persistent protocol like MQTT or websockets.

Comment: @romkey It has taken me a couple of weeks to get it up and going but MQTT and websockets were exactly what I needed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.